# change JPanel after clicking on a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm building simple GUI for my app. I have couple of JPanels. I want to display them depending on action that was performed by clicking on a JButton. How can I disable one JPanel and enable another one ?

Couple of details. I have a class with JFrame where I'm building starting gui. Where I have buttons and some text. Clicking on one of the buttons should change the view in this JFrame

my button definition

```
    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    btnStart.setBounds(10, 11, 110, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnStart);
```

// edit

I've found the problem. buttons were in static method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple as:

```
jframe.setContentPane(your_new_panel);
jframe.invalidate();
jframe.validate();
```

Comment: How can i get jframe ? This is internal class so it has no access to it

Comment: If you are extending JFrame, you already have access to the method setContentPane.

Comment: That single code line will not succeed in changing the component displayed.

Answer (score 5):

1. You may want to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
2. Or you can simple remove the oldpanel and add new panel:

---

```
contentPane.remove(oldPanel);
contentPane.add(newPanel);
```

Comment: same question as above. How to get to the contentPane from internal class ?

Comment: @Fixus:  you don't need to get the contentPane. You just need a reference to whatever class is handling the cardlayout-using component, and call whatever public method you've given the class that will have you swap cards. To Suraj: your CardLayout rec is better than swapping components, since CardLayout will take component size into consideration. Also you don't have to worry about calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` (which you seem to have forgotten in your answer).

Comment: if its a JFrame, you could get the contentPane using: "frame.getContentPane()"

Comment: I`ve updated my code. I don`t have access to setContentPane() :/ found the problem. I'll check your example

Answer (score 1):

First remove the jPanel and add the new jPanel. Then use validate to perform relayout.

```
    jFrame.remove(jPanelOld);
    jFrame.add(jPanelNew);
    jFrame.validate();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please also write some text, not only a code snippet? (Please edit your post)

Comment: Thanks. I added a text. :)